# Strain-stress relationship in spherical coordinates with Poisson's ratio

Tags: symbolic, education

I am wondering if there is a way to get the relationship between strain and stress in spherical coordinates with Poisson's ratio. I read the documentation here:

https://reference.wolfram.com/applications/structural/GoverningEquationsofElasticity.html

but there is only the relationship between strain and stress in spherical coordinates with Lamè's coefficients.

Comment: See the function `ConvertCoefficients` in section 7.2.6 "Elasticity Coefficients" in the source you gave...

Comment: Thank you @HenrikSchumacher